# Is it possible to install or move my installed Linux to another partition?

Tags: filesystem, partition

Case scenario (a SD Card with **three partitons**: a boot partition, and two Linux-type partitions) :

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 61.9 GB, 61924704256 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 1889792 cylinders, total 120946688 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000697c0

        Device Boot      Start         End       Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1               1      125000        62500    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2          133120    62945279     31406080   83  Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p3        62945279   120946687    28410843+   83  Linux
```

The **usual place** for Ubuntu and Kali seems to be `/dev/mmcblk0p2`, for what I have tested until now (the `.img` image file creates the system root there).

Is it **possible** to install some Linux distribution on `/dev/mmcblk0p3` or move it from `/dev/mmcblk0p2` after installed?

Generic **any-Linux** answers are preferred. If not possible, I would go for Ubuntu, as it is a very popular distro.

Additional points:

- This is the official [tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition) for system partition moving on Ubuntu (desktop version). But I think it could not be the proper one. For example: there is no need GRUB for RaspBerry, as long as I know.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to install some Linux distribution on /dev/mmcblk0p3

Yes.

> or move it from /dev/mmcblk0p2 after installed?

Yes; your primary concern is the content of `/etc/fstab`.  After you move the partition, check that file for references to the partition you moved from, and update them; e.g. `/dev/mmcblk0p2` -> `/dev/mmcblk0p3`.

If you do not know how to actually move/copy the contents of a partition, it is identical to [the process described here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5492/5538) for creating a backup, since the purpose of the backup is to be used as a drop-in replacement for the original filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the 3rd time ([1st](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/30169/), [2nd](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33884/)) you have asked this question. It's a bit better this time but clearly you are not asking specific enough  questions.

1. install kali on an sdcard or mount an img of it on loopback (use **[dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)**, or **[mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)**)
2. copy the files to a computer (use **[cp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp)**, **[rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)**, **[dd](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)**, or the like)
3. do the same with Ubuntu
4. make a fresh partition table on the sdcard with 3 partitions with the correct flags and file systems (use **[fdisk](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk)**, **[parted](http://linux.die.net/man/8/parted)**, or the like)
5. copy the files back to the card but only copy boot from Ubuntu and copy each boot to there respective /opt/boot/ubuntu/ folders. you may have to edit /etc/fstab for kali
6. re-read the answers to your other 2 questions to select what to boot.

if you copy the files use rsync -a or the like to preserve file flags, if you copy whole partitions using dd do it from loopback or otherwise make sure they have not been expanded to the whole card.
A bootable img is a dd copy of the whole partition table / disk.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If this question has been asked three times, I think I must delete the others two questions. I have reviewed all my questions on this forum, and I am not able to find them. Could you please refer them with a (two) link?